# find information, such as size, about default charset in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, hashcode

So *I* know that the size of the ASCII charset is 256. But how do I ask Java for the size of its default charset? And what if I wanted to change the charset? Would the change affect the `hashCode` function of Character and String? I am trying to create a hash function for Rabin-Karp and I want to use

```
preModHash = preModHash*BASE+c.hashCode();//where c is a Character
```

actually since each char has an int value I could simply do

```
preModHash = preModHash*BASE+c;//where c is a char
```

Comment: Wait, the size of the Unicode charset is 256? 256 what? Define "size of a charset".

Comment: sorry. I meant ASCII

Comment: ASCII actually has 128 characters, stored in 7 bits.

Comment: @RealSkeptic at the very least you see why I need help with this problem. :)

Comment: A `char` in Java is always 16bit encoding codepoints in UTF-16. You might not use all of the codepoints, but for the purpose of hashcode caldulation it is best to not care.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really such a thing as "size" for a charset. And some interesting options like the largest known code point are not available. Having said that it is a bit unfortunate that the `Charset` class does not offer any informational attributed.

But as I said above for the purpose of `char` in `hashCode()` thats not really interesting: It is in Java always a 16bit UTF-16 code unit, and while the value space might depend on the encoding you can always expect the lower bits to have the highest entropy.

Comment: The entropy doesn't really matter, as `hashCode()` returns `int` which is 4 bytes, and `char` only has 2 bytes. Hence a unique hash code is possible for all characters.

Comment: for an example, I mentioned the Rabin-Karp algorithm. So how would I decide what the radix (i.e. BASE) is for my computation of the hash? Do I just pick 256 or 128 out of think air? I see a professor using 256 for Java. But why would he do that?

Comment: The "entropy" and "value range" matters when you combine multiple values with a bad factor (for example two characters with a small factor, then you get a lot of same hashcodes for different order of the same chars. (see for example https://gist.github.com/ecki/9f69773eb29428a36077)

Comment: `String#hashCode()` uses BTW `31^(l-i-1)`